# How to can I include Custom JavaScript in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How Can I include a Custom JavaScript in ReactJS and use Array of Object in that?
I am trying to display a list of songs. So, I have created a file with the name **songList.js** and inside that, I have created an Array of objects how can I include it in my **list.js** file and use it inside that?

**songList.js Code :-**

```
const songList = [{
        name: "All We Know",
        artist: "The Chainsmokers ft. Phoebe Ryan",
        album: "All We Know",
    },
    {
        name: "Alone",
        artist: "Alan Walker",
        album: "Different World",
    },
    {
        name: "Be Kind",
        artist: "Marshmello & Halsey",
        album: "Be Kind",
    },
    {
        name: "Beach House",
        artist: "The Chainsmokers",
        album: "Sick Boy",
    },
];
```

I am trying to do this but it is not working please tell me where I am wrong?

**list.js code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './songList.js'

export class list extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {songList[0].name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default list
```

Comment: You need to export the list (using `export default songList`), then import it using `import songList from './songList.js'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you export the object, then import it correctly:

```
export const songList = ...

import { songList } from './songList.js';
```